# Wrong image is displayed on browser breakpoints

Tags: php, html, css, mobile

I wrote a PHP image display function. There is no problem with the function. But I have a problem with breakpoints. On mobile it shows the big picture. I couldn't understand how to solve the problem.

```
function imglazy($filen,$altn,$classn) {
    global $imagepath;
    global $cdnsource;
echo '<picture>
<source media="(min-width: 1025px)"
    data-srcset="'.$cdnsource.$imagepath.$filen.'-fl.webp"
    type="image/webp">
<source media="(max-width: 1024px)"
    data-srcset="'.$cdnsource.$imagepath.$filen.'-bg.webp"
    type="image/webp">
<source media="(max-width: 768px)"
    data-srcset="'.$cdnsource.$imagepath.$filen.'-md.webp"
    type="image/webp">
<source media="(max-width: 500px)"
    data-srcset="'.$cdnsource.$imagepath.$filen.'-sm.webp"
    type="image/webp">

<source media="(min-width: 1025px)"
    data-srcset="'.$cdnsource.$imagepath.$filen.'-fl.jpg"
    type="image/jpeg">
<source media="(max-width: 1024px)"
    data-srcset="'.$cdnsource.$imagepath.$filen.'-bg.jpg"
    type="image/jpeg">
<source media="(max-width: 768px)"
    data-srcset="'.$cdnsource.$imagepath.$filen.'-md.jpg"
    type="image/jpeg">
<source media="(max-width: 500px)"
    data-srcset="'.$cdnsource.$imagepath.$filen.'-sm.jpg"
    type="image/jpeg">
<img
    data-srcset="'.$cdnsource.$imagepath.$filen.'-bg.jpg,
        '.$cdnsource.$imagepath.$filen.'-md.jpg,
        '.$cdnsource.$imagepath.$filen.'-sm.jpg"
    data-src="'.$cdnsource.$imagepath.$filen.'-fl.jpg"
    alt="'.$altn.'"
    class="lazyload '.$classn.'">
</picture>';
}
```

Comment: media only screen and (max-width: 600px) { .img{ Max-width:100%; height:auto; } }  Use this and check

Comment: I use data-srcset for lazy load

Comment: @Yunus I feel like your combining couple of ways to load those images. I dont believe you need to define other sizes in your `<img>` tag since your already defining them in your `<source media="">` tags. [According to the docs it seems you should only do it 1 of the 2 ways.](https://imagekit.io/responsive-images/#lazy-loading-images-in-picture-element)

Comment: after image tag; data-srcset > I need to delete it. yes?